# Why does FindBugs complain that .collect(toSet()) might return null?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, findbugs

I have the following code, which as far as I can see it cannot return null:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public static @Nonnull Set<String> foo() {
    return Arrays.asList("a","b","c").stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()); // line 166
}
```

But FindBugs complains with a `NP_NONNULL_RETURN_VIOLATION` error.

```
[INFO] MyClass.foo() may return null, 
   but is declared @Nonnull [MyClass, MyClass]
   Returned at MyClass.java:[line 166]
   Known null at MyClass.java:[line 166]
   NP_NONNULL_RETURN_VIOLATION
```

I have checked the documentation to "collect" and "toSet" and they don't mention anything about nulls, neither that they return them, nor that they don't. But I can't imagine a situation in which that returns null.

I was thinking maybe FindBugs just doesn't understand Java 8 stream features. But FindBugs otherwise does seem to understand Java 8 features (e.g. the `@Nonnull` annotation itself.)

I am using the FindBugs Maven Plug-in version 3.0.4, and my source depends on the FindBugs 3.0.1 in Maven. I understand these are the latest versions at the time of writing.

(The code may appear to be a bit pointless, it's just an example.)

Comment: what findBugs version is that?

Comment: The “`@Nonnull` annotation itself” is not a Java 8 feature. In fact, there are no such annotations on the JRE classes. Therefore, FindBugs et al have to know each method and their nullability when it comes to the JRE classes. If no-one told FindBugs that `toSet()` never returns `null`, it doesn’t know.

Comment: @Holger so.. that should be wrapped into a `if == null` to silence findbugs? that sounds like a bug in findbugs to me; but not sure how one can fix that

Comment: @Eugene: I’m only telling the problem, i.e. the reluctance of the JRE developers to finally add a standardized `@NonNull` annotation. Since FindBugs tries to cope with that, it has to know each method and if a method is missing (or recorded with a wrong default), its database/config file has to be updated. You can consider it a bug in FindBugs, but don’t be too harsh to its developers, it’s a hard task to maintain the defaults for all JRE methods…

Comment: @Holger not being harsh on them at all.. `but not sure how one can fix that`

Comment: also.. I wonder if you should really be using this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305

Comment: `@SuppressFBWarnings`…

Comment: `collect()` will return `null` if the collector produces a `null` result. This is probably difficult or even impossible to check for FindBugs though.

Comment: Yes I see, so it would involve FindBugs knowing that the relationship in "collect" is that its nullability depends on whether its parameter can return null. And also knowing that toSet cannot return null (if that's the case, which I assume). Yes, it's a difficult one for FindBugs for sure.

Comment: @Holger , if you write that as an answer, I'll accept it as the right answer.